# Getting "Not a valid choice" with wtforms select field in Flask app, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

all. I am working on a Flask application. I am developing a website for a restaurant with an online ordering system. I'm doing this for a friend and taking it as a learning experience. The issue I am going to ask about is probably a small one. I am not sure whether the issue is more with wtforms or flask-wtf. Hopefully someone can provide some insight.

I am creating a shopping cart, with a few buttons that are rendered through `wtf.quick_form`. Here is that:

```
<div id='cart'>
    <div>
        <p>
        <center><b>Shopping cart</b></center>
        </p>
        <div>
            {% for item in requested_item_record %}
            <div id='cartI'>{{list_of_items[item]['name']}}</div>
            <div id='cartB'> {{ wtf.quick_form(remove_item_dict[item]) }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <p id='cartT'>Subtotal: {{ total_cost/100 }} </p>

        <p id='cartT'>Tax: {{ tax/100 }}</p>

        <p id='cartT'>Total: {{ total/100 }}</p>

        <div id='cartB'>{{ wtf.quick_form(clear_cart) }}</div>
        <div id='cartB'>{{ wtf.quick_form(order_type) }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the buttons defined by `wtforms`:

```
class AddItem(Form):
        submit = SubmitField("Add item to cart")

class ClearCart(Form):
        submit = SubmitField("Clear cart")

class RemoveItem(Form):
        submit = SubmitField("Remove item")

class OrderType(Form):
        select = SelectField("Pickup or delivery?", choices=[('pickup','Pickup'),('delivery','Delivery')])
        submit = SubmitField("Proceed to checkout")
```

The **problem** is that I am seeing **"Not a valid choice"** below the `SelectField` from the `OrderType` button. I think this will confuse users. I am not sure how to remove it though. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I only see the behavior if I submit data with one of the `RemoveItem` buttons or the `ClearCart` button.

Here is the relevant portion of my view function:

```
# generate add buttons for all items of the menu
button_dict = OrderedDict([])
for i in range(number_of_submit_buttons):
    button_dict[i] = AddItem(prefix='add item ' + str(i))
clear_cart = ClearCart(prefix="clear cart")

# check for submit data from users, remove an item or clear cart.
for iterable, add_button in enumerate(button_dict):
    if button_dict[add_button].validate_on_submit and button_dict[add_bu$
        session['requested_item_record'].append(iterable)
        session['total_cost'] += list_of_items[iterable]['price']
if clear_cart.validate_on_submit and clear_cart.submit.data:
    session['requested_item_record'] = []
    session['total_cost'] = 0

# select field, for delivery or pickup
order_type = OrderType(prefix='order_type')
if order_type.validate_on_submit() and order_type.submit.data:
        if order_type.select.data == 'delivery' and session['requested_i$
            return redirect(url_for('transaction.get_address'))
        elif order_type.select.data == 'pickup' and session['requested_i$
            return redirect(url_for('transaction.checkout'))
```

The functionality is fine. The website works how I want it to, just for some reason I am getting this error of "Not a valid choice". This appears only when I use one of the remove item or clear cart buttons.

Comment: View functions, or single function?  If you've got all that code under one view, then clicking a button on the other forms will make the `validate_on_submit()` function for the `order_type` fail, which will give you the error you're seeing.  Split them into different views, or detect which form is being submitted and **only** process the logic for that form.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I think that will solve it. I will look into this tomorrow. You can write up an answer if you like.

Comment: I am already using [this method](http://librelist.com/browser/flask/2010/9/12/flask-wtf-multiple-form-per-view/#d8cfeff63b89d028919d4617ed642d15) to identify different submit buttons. As I said, the functionality works just fine. Each time  I click on one of the buttons, it performs the task I want it to without any errors. But I am getting "Not a valid selection". So the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, I think, in this line:

```
if order_type.validate_on_submit() and order_type.submit.data:
```

Here you unconditionally validate the `OrderType` form, so any time you click on the other buttons the validation for this form is going to fail due to the select drop down not having a value.

Try reversing the two parts of the conditional, as follows:

```
if order_type.submit.data and order_type.validate_on_submit():
```

In this way, the validation will only be done when the submit button for that form has value, which indicates that that's the form that was submitted by the user.